How to enable Gnosis Safe Recovery module via SDK or API when deploying the Gnosis Safe contract?
I must set up the Gnosis Safe Recovery module when deploying the Gnosis Safe contract via JS app. (currently using the SDK for the contract deployment https://docs.safe.global/sdk/protocol-kit#deploy-a-safe)
As I read this article https://help.safe.global/en/articles/110656-account-recovery-with-safe-recoveryhub, it looks like it's only possible to do it via Safe{Wallet}UI, there is no more info in the official docs.
Is it possible to enable the Recovery module via SDK/API?
Or do I have to deploy the Delay contract https://github.com/gnosisguild/zodiac-modifier-delay/blob/main/docs/setup_guide.md myself and then call the 2 transactions to enable the modules?


The Recovery Hub is simply a Zodiac Delay Modifier configured so that an address can act as a "Recoverer". There is currently no method dedicated to this in the SDK, although you could simply use the SDK to prepare and execute the transactions that would enable the Zodiac modifier in your Safe.
You can also use Rhinestone's Social Recovery Module for a similar outcome. A tutorial specifically dedicated to this will be released shortly to showcase this module in the Safe docs.
Let me know if it answered your question; Best, Louis

Hey Louis, thanks for your response.  What I'm doing right now:

Deploying safe via: safeFactory.deploySafe(...)
Deploying Recoverer Module (Delay contract) via [ModuleProxyFactory]: (https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x000000000000aDdB49795b0f9bA5BC298cDda236#code)
Calling MultiSend transaction where I enable the module in the Gnosis Safe contract and Delay contract.

Is it possible to do it in fewer steps?

This sounds right! It will not necessary to deploy a new Recoverer module each time a safe is deployed; but other than that your approach seems correct! You could also try to batch the safe deployment transaction with the transaction enabling the module using the Safe 4337 pack in the relay kit: https://docs.safe.global/sdk/relay-kit/guides/4337-safe-sdk. This would reduce the number of steps required down to 1 single transaction. Hope it helps! Best, Louis

Every recoverer module (Delay contract) needs an Avatar, and Avatar = Gnosis Safe. So this means that 1 Gnosis Safe needs to have 1 Delay contract, right? E.g. This is a recoverer module https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xD0D989a05c84AA7C867Bd5D89203aBF945c44D13#readContract for this Gnosis Safe 0xA7C949E121C61001FEa7d2d7d8B3523d8317d016. Zodiac docs: https://github.com/gnosisguild/zodiac-modifier-delay/blob/main/docs/setup_guide.md#deploying-the-modifier

Apologies, you are correct. You will need to deploy a new module per safe.

Is it possible to predict the address of the recoverer module address (Delay contract deployed via ModuleProxyFactory.sol https://github.com/gnosisguild/zodiac/blob/master/contracts/factory/ModuleProxyFactory.sol) before its deployment? If yes, then I would be able to deploy the Recoverer module alongside enabling the modules, so I would be able to do it in 2 steps.

Yes, since the ModuleProxyFactory uses create2 to deploy the contract (see line 32 of the contract you shared) it should be possible to calculate in advance its address. You could use a similar function than the getAddress one, found in the following example: https://solidity-by-example.org/app/create2/

You can also use this function from ethers.js: https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/address/#getCreate2Address or this one from viem: https://viem.sh/docs/utilities/getContractAddress
